# What does the symbol '#' in a parameter list of a function mean?

Tags: c

I am new to C, what exactly does `#algo` do here?

```c
#define run(algo) execute(&algo, #algo)
```

In the function definition of `execute` it looks like it's somehow used for constant parameters ...

```c
void execute(int (*algo_func)(int *, int, int), const char * algo_name)
{
    int hit = 0, miss = 0;

...
```

I found this here at line 408: https://github.com/scandum/binary_search/blob/master/binary-search.c

Comment: It is called stringification: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [preprocessor stringizing operator](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html). The preprocessor replaces `#algo` with whatever was passed to the `run()` macro converted to a string literal, so:

```
run(some_algorithm)
```

would be changed to:

```
execute(&some_algorithm, "some_algorithm")
```